# jquery - remove last div in a group

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the very last DIV identified by id begining with letters "section"  (eg: "section99")
in a DIV identified by id="groupA"

```
currentTab = "A";

$('#subPart').click(function() { 
    name = "#group" + currentTab;   
        ....

    $(something).remove();              
    return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This script

```
   $('#groupA').find('div[id^="section"]:last').remove();
```

Comment: Worked without quotes. Are they optional?

Comment: Documentation says quotes are mandatory, http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: @bob 2 what about checking it as correct answer to your question

Comment: @powtac but the documentations also says it added in version one of jquery, may be it is not mandatory in the latest version, and too I am not sure

Comment: @Miroprocessor: true, but I recommend to use it.

Comment: @powtac I agree,I think the code will be more readable and meaningful with it